# How to decode a base64 PDF string to HTML content to show in the WebView Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, base64

I have searched the question in google but there weren't any proper answer to my question. I receive a base64 PDF string from the web service so I want to decode it to HTML content and show the content in the WebView Android using Kotlin.

The base64 PDF string which I receive looks like this:

```
JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz9MNCjI1IDAgb2JqDTw8L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9GaXJzdCA5L0xlbmd0aCAxNjAvTiAyL1R5cGUvT2JqU3RtPj5zdHJlYW0NChmTCzbz2u1ECXhRoEhFO5hqM5RwR4FRuV0pXQ0mGWWQhxuo9vSP+sli4xR6MLwMRkd6pwDn4OCx61I2M+jEkDjUoe+v7TZrF7OuB/XqWmXaqR172e28BVjvMkUI64XPyfMCCAPOxfrw0LXOuYjvKnkZix9v5fSJOvwWJV2LNki2C2+ZwO5JBjHYob8BYWEh39N1A2GAj/n5AAzXIZB2v...
```

I can't download the PDF file and save it or use any third party libraries since it is restricted in the requirements therefore I just want to show the PDF only. Please help me to find a solution to this, I have been stuck on this. Thank you in advance...

Comment: A base64 encoded pdf you can decode to a pdf document. But converting a pdf document to an html page is quite something different. Quite a challenge. Tell how you would do that.

Comment: Please share the details how I can convert an encoded pdf to pdf document without downloading the document @blackapps

Comment: Of course you have to download that base64 encoded string. It should be transfered from server to your device first of course. But you dont have to save that string to storage in order to decode it

Comment: downloading the pdf to the device is restricted. Please suggest another method @blackapps

Comment: I think that saving to storage is restricted. But you have to get that base64 encoded string from server first. This is called downloading. There is no other way. And you can imagine that there is no other way then getting that string first to the device. If it stays on the server your app can do nothing with it.